# Find a string has two overlapped string PHP

Tags: php

I have two strings `abc` and `bca`. I want to check whether an other string contains these both the strings and are not overlapped too. For example:

1. a string **abca** contains both but is overlapped.
2. a string **abcxbca** contains both and not overlapped.
3. a string **abcxbcabc** contains both but is overlapped.

Comment: what did you try so far? please add your code following [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy :)

```
    <?php 

    $y1="abc"; //search string1
    $y2="bca"; //search string2

    $x1="abca"; //contains both but is overlapped.
    $x2= "abcxbca"; //contains both and not overlapped.
    $x3 ="abcxbcabc"; //contains both but is overlapped.

    class Points{
    public $start;
    public $stop;
    public $overlaped=false;

    private function Points( $s1, $s2 ) {
        $this->start=$s1;
        $this->stop=$s2;
        $this->overlaped=false;
    }


    public static function create($s1, $s2){
        if (is_numeric($s1)&&is_numeric($s2)){
            return new Points($s1, $s2);
        }
    else return NULL;
    }


}  

function display($arr){
    $cnt1=0;
    $cnt2=0;
    for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
        if ($arr[$i]->overlaped===true) $cnt1++;
        else $cnt2++;
    }

    return " ".$cnt2." not overlaped and ".$cnt1." overlaped";
}

function strpos_all($haystack, $needle) {  
    $offset = 0;
    $allpos = array();

    while (($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset)) !== FALSE) {
        $offset   = $pos + 1;
        $allpos[] = Points::create($pos,$pos+strlen($needle));
    }
    return $allpos;   }


     function check($haystack,$needle1,$needle2){

    $find1= strpos_all($haystack, $needle1);

    $find2= strpos_all($haystack, $needle2);



    for ($i=0;$i<count($find1);$i++){
        for($j =0; $j<count($find2);$j++){
            if (max($find1[$i]->start,$find2[$j]->start) <= min($find1[$i]->stop,$find2[$j]->stop)) {
              $find1[$i]->overlaped=true;
              $find2[$j]->overlaped=true;
            }
        }
    }

    echo  $needle1.display($find1)."<br>"; 
    echo  $needle2.display($find2)."<br>"; 

}

echo "<br>------Start-------<br>";
echo "String :".$x1."<br>";
check ($x1,$y1,$y2);
echo "<br>-----End----------<br>";

echo "<br>------Start-------<br>";
echo "String :".$x2."<br>";
check ($x2,$y1,$y2);
echo "<br>-----End--------<br>";

echo "<br>------Start-------<br>";
echo "String :".$x3."<br>";
check ($x3,$y1,$y2);
echo "<br>-----End--------<br>";

?>
```